# How to remove the Javascript script added to webdriver using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have executed a Javascript in Webdriver using JavascriptExecutor and this script remains in the document until I refresh the page. I wonder is there a way to remove this script or disable it after executing it once and without refreshing the page?

```
js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript();
```

Comment: Can we see the script? What exactly are you trying to disable?

Comment: @ekuusela                                                                                                      js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200, height=100'); myWindow.document.write('Javascript added');");

This is a sample script. When i run this via webdriver, this snippet it injected to my page source and remains active there until I reload the page. I don't want to keep that code in my page source after executing it just once, even though its temporary..!